# Create new rows by summing and subtracting existing rows

Tags: r

This is my current data

| Year | Economy | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | US | 350 |
| 2000 | China | 450 |
| 2000 | World | 2250 |
| 2001 | US | 320 |
| 2001 | China | 430 |
| 2001 | World | 2140 |

I want to add another row called "Rest of the World" for each year, by summing values for the US and China, then subtract from the World value. That is Rest of the World = World - (US + China).
My final data should look like this. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

| Year | Economy | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | US | 350 |
| 2000 | China | 450 |
| 2000 | World | 2250 |
| 2000 | Rest of the World | 1450 |
| 2001 | US | 320 |
| 2001 | China | 430 |
| 2001 | World | 2140 |
| 2001 | Rest of the World | 1390 |

Comment: Can you share where you're stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
   group_split(Year) %>%
   map_dfr(~ .x %>%
               add_row(Year = first(.x$Year), 
          Economy = "Rest of the World",
         GDP = .x$GDP[.x$Economy == "World"] - sum(.x$GDP[.x$Economy != "World"])))
```